# ¿Como compilar pug(antes jade) a php con gulp?

Tags: php, html, gulp, jade

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que es necesario trabajar con .php, siempre he trabajado con .html, pero ahora tengo que trabajarlo con .php, yo trabajo con pug antes llamado jade y lo compilo por medio de tareas en gulp, pero por default se compila en html, pero quiero saber si hay forma de pasarlo a php con gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema se me presento al tener la exigencia del programador para usar declaraciones php y así manejar la sesiones en el sitio sin usar sessionStorage, pues teníamos problemas con cache, y no querer separa la maquetación que tenia en .pug.

La solución a este problema fue muy sencilla.

1. Revisar si .pug no tenia conflictos con el tag , esto lo hice en codepen.io
2. Luego buscar un modulo en npm que pueda manejar el cambio de extensión, la solución la encontré con este módulo: gulp-rename.
3. Ya con eso modifique mi tarea del gulp:

```js
var // Modulos de desarrollo
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  pug = require('gulp-pug'),
  rename = require("gulp-rename");


gulp.task('views', function() {
  gulp
    .src('./' + desarrollo + '/pug/*.pug', {
      base: './' + desarrollo + '/pug/'
    })
    // -------------------------------------
    .pipe(pug({
      locals: {},
      pretty: true
    }))
    // ------------------------------------- 
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ".php"
    }))
    // ------------------------------------- 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

```html
html
  head title php in my pug 
  body 
    main
    // Declaración php
    <?php echo 'I`m a php'?>
    h1 Hello #[br] #[small &lt;?php echo 'pug' ?&gt;]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un paquete de npm llamado gulp-jade-php ademas de pug

[jade-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade-php)

Ejemplo de uso:

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade-php');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
gulp.src('./views/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        locals: {
        title: 'OMG THIS IS THE TITLE'
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: lo he utilizado pero no da resultado

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema? Yo he probado el paquete y funciona bien